# Multiple View where one will change based on State or Url and others with stay same [Angular UI Router]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try to create a blog for me by using Angular and ASP.NET Web API. 
Here is my `Layout.cshtml`

```
<div id="header">
    <div data-ui-view="menu"></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div data-ui-view></div>
    <div data-ui-view="sidebar"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div data-ui-view="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And views by using `text/ng-template`

```
<!-- Layout Views -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Menu.html">
   <div>
     <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
     <a ui-sref="register">Register</a>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Sidebar.html">
   <div>Sidebar</div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Footer.html">
   <div>Footer</div>
</script>

<!-- Page Views -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Home.html">
   <div>Home</div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Register.html">
   <div>Register</div>
   <a ui-sref="home">Back</a>
</script>
```

And Here is `app.js`

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
           .state('home', {
                url: '/',
               views: {
                 '': {
                   templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Home.html'
                 },
                 'menu@': {
                   templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Menu.html'
                 },
                 'sidebar@': {
                   templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Sidebar.html'
                 },
                 'footer@': {
                   templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Footer.html'
                 }
               }
           }).state('register', {
               url: '^/Register',
               templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Register.html'
        });
  }]);
```

Here is what i want:

1. When i browse home page `(domain/#/)` it will replace unnamed view with `Home.html`
2. When i browse register page `(domain/#/Register)` or clicked on `Register` from menu, it will replace unnamed view with `Register.html`

As per now, `domain/#/` is working fine but `(domain/#/Register)` only shows `Register` view whereas it should have shown other 3 (menu, sidebar, footer) views also.

[**CODEPEN LINK**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amQJQp?editors=1010#0)

I check stackoverflow & different blogs for 2 days but can't solve the issue. What I miss here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could accomplish this is to have an abstract "master" state where you define the templates for the named views and then "children" of this "master" for your `home` and `register` states. Here is an example adapted directly from your Codepen:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
      $stateProvider
        .state('master', {
          abstract: true,
          views: {
            'menu@': {
              templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Menu.html'
            },
            'sidebar@': {
              templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Sidebar.html'
            },
            'footer@': {
              templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Footer.html'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('master.home', {
          url: '/',
          views: {
            '@': {
              templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Home.html'
            }
          }


        }).state('master.register', {
          url: '/Register',
          views: {
            '@': {
              templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Register.html'
            }
          }

        });
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div id="header">
    <div data-ui-view="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div data-ui-view></div>
    <div data-ui-view="sidebar"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div data-ui-view="footer"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Layout Views-->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Menu.html">
    <div>
      <a ui-sref="master.home">Home</a>
      <a ui-sref="master.register">Register</a>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Sidebar.html">
    <div>Sidebar</div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Footer.html">
    <div>Footer</div>
  </script>

  <!-- Page Views-->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Home.html">
    <div>Home</div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Register.html">
    <div>Register</div>
    <a ui-sref="master.home">Back</a>
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's work for me. I actually want something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use child states any time you want certain views to stick around.  How you have it set up, `register` state is not a child of anything, so when you switch to it - all the views get reset!

Two changes you need to make:

Define `register` as a child state of `home`:

```
.state('home.register', {
    url: 'Register',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: '/Templates/Layout/Register.html'
        }
    }
```

Update the `ui-sref` in the menu:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/Templates/Layout/Menu.html">
    <div>
        <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
        <a ui-sref="home.register">Register</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/plong0/pen/EgOmzR?editors=1011)

Please review `ui-router` docs on [nested states and nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) and [multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

@Lex's answer to have a base master/root/layout state is also really good and works well in more complex situations.  My answer is the very simple, minimum to make your code working.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer works for me with minimum change of my code. But for future, i will use @Lex's answer.